# When do I use Param rather than Const in Gekko?

Tags: python, gekko

I'm trying to fit a cubic spline to the data points below, I'm a bit confused when I would use a `Param` like the example `m.x = m.Param(value=np.linspace(-1, 6))` or when I would use a constant `Const`.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
xm = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ym = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0, 0.9])

m = GEKKO()
m.x = m.Param(value=np.linspace(-1, 6))
m.y = m.Var()
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.cspline(m.x, m.y, xm, ym)
m.solve(disp=False)

p = GEKKO()
p.x = p.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=5)
p.y = p.Var()
p.cspline(p.x, p.y, xm, ym)
p.Obj(-p.y)
p.solve(disp=False)
```

Comment: FYI: there is a new `Maximize` function in gekko so that your objective function can be more readable with `p.Maximize(p.y)` instead of `p.Obj(-p.y)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constant `Const` is a single scalar value that is not expected to change. A parameter `Param` has an initial value but it can be changed by the user with data. A fixed value `FV` or manipulated variable `MV` are two special types of parameters that have [extra options](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuning_params.html) for becoming a solver decision variable. The difference between an `FV` and `MV` is that an `FV` has one value while an `MV` can have different values across the data (`IMODE=2`) or time (`IMODE=4-9`) dimension.

You have a nice example of fitting a cubic spline to data and then solving for the maximum across the range `0 < x < 5`.

[image: Cubic spline maximization]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
xm = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ym = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0, 0.9])

m = GEKKO()
m.x = m.Param(value=np.linspace(-1, 6))
m.y = m.Var()
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.cspline(m.x, m.y, xm, ym)
m.solve(disp=False)

p = GEKKO()
p.x = p.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=5)
p.y = p.Var()
p.cspline(p.x, p.y, xm, ym)
p.Maximize(p.y)
p.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xm,ym,'rs',label='Data')
plt.plot(m.x,m.y,'r.-',label='Cubic Spline')
plt.plot(p.x,p.y,'bo',label='Maximize')
plt.xlabel('x'), plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

In your case, a `Param` (or `MV` with `STATUS=0`) is the appropriate gekko object. A `Const` gives an error: `ValueError: Constant value must be scalar.`